# How can insert data using the select statement

Tags: sql

How can I insert data using the select statement...

I have come across a question asking, what is `select * from orders;` used for? 
And the answer was for viewing and inserting ....

Please provide an explanation ...

Comment: The correct answer is "nothing, unless you are doing ad hoc queries during development".

Answer (score 2):

The answer *"for viewing and inserting"* is misleading and incomplete; [`SELECT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) returns data, which can then be used in almost *any* SQL statement.

For most normal use cases, you insert data using an [`INSERT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) statement.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyColumn)
VALUES ('MyValue')
```

In some cases you may want to insert data that you are pulling from another table (or view), in which case you might use this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyColumn)
SELECT MyColumn
FROM MyTableOrMyOtherTableOrView
```

Note that the exact syntax may vary depending upon your database platform.

Comment: Then what is , select into " is for ?

Comment: That is a variation on `INSERT INTO...SELECT...`

Answer (score 0):

To insert values based on a select use this syntax:

```
insert into table1 (mycol)
select mycol from table2
```

You can also use `select into` that enables you to create a new table : [select into](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)

And `select * from table1` means select every column from table1

For a full tutorial on SQL try [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You use

`insert into tableX(columnsX) select columnsY from tableY`

to insert data from `tableY` to `tableX`. They can both be the same. `columnsY` is a list of columns that exists in tableY and it must match column types in tableY.

That basically means that you'll be inserting existing data into tableX, and that existing data comes from tableY.

For the question,

`"what is "select * from orders ;" used for?"`

the answer

`for viewing and inserting`

is not correct. It is only for viewing, not inserting.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void cnd()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = serverName;User ID  = serverId;Password = serverPassword;Initial Catalog = DatabaseName");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tableName", con);
        SqlCommandBuilder cmdbuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dp);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("tableName");
        dp.Fill(ds, "tableName");
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables["tableName"].NewRow();
        dr["columnName"] = "Value";
        dr["columnName"] = "Value";
        ds.Tables["tableName"].Rows.Add(dr);
       int re =  dp.Update(ds, "tableName");
       Console.WriteLine(re.ToString());
       con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some explanation as well?